# How to scale Cassandra cluster vertically

Tags: scalability, cassandra, scale

I have a 3 node Cassandra cluster which I set up a year ago and it is getting quite slow now. It is much cheaper for me to scale vertically than it would be to scale horizontally ( I received free RAM and new gigabit nic cards which I want to put into my nodes). I need the cluster to remain up while I upgrade, but I can't find any documentation on how to scale vertically with no downtime.  What is the standard procedure to scale a Cassandra cluster vertically? As well, do all the machines need to be identical (same amount of ram, same harddrive space, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the standard procedure to scale a Cassandra cluster vertically?

There is not. Cassandra was designed to scale horizontally, although you can try to scale it vertically. Simply upgrade one node by one.

- Read about [hinted handoff](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html) - the mechanism which will be used when one of your nodes will be down
- Make sure your clients use proper ConsistencyLevel (as hinted handoff isn't counted for consistency level)
- [Read what happens after node comes back online](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeFailDetect_c.html)

> As well, do all the machines need to be identical (same amount of ram, same harddrive space, etc)?

No, but you will have to do load balancing manually. If you will have 4 'old' nodes and one 'upgraded' node, and load will be the same on them (the same number of writes/reads because of token assigment), obviously 'old' nodes will have higher percent of theirs resource usage.